# How can include a version id in my jar archive's inf file with Android Studio?

Tags: jar, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the following gradle script to build jar files in AndroidStudio, but I am getting a `Could not find method jar()` error when I include that part. Anyone knows how this can be done with the `com.android.library` plugin?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "MyProject Name",
                "Implementation-Version": "v1-1-0")
    }
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/myjar.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myjar.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

Comment: Why using `com.android.library` if you only intend to create jar? Just `java` plugin would suffice. Is it an android project?

Comment: There are some things I need from the 'com.android.library' plugin. I did not include the whole gradle file.